# Importing ace editor into emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ace-editor

How can I import ace editor elements into an ember-cli project.

Trying to following:

```
//Brocfile.js
app.import('bower_components/ace/src/ace.js');
```

Now inside a component I want to import something from ace:

```
//custom-component.js
import oop from 'ace/lib/oop'
import TextHighlightRules from 'ace/mode/text_highlight_rules'
```

Inside the **didInsertElement** I can't get a hold of **oop** or **TextHighlightRules**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found Ace to be tricky to install since it wants to be able to load its JS files as required at run time. This means you need to keep the Ace JS directory structure intact in your build output.

So here's what I did to "import" Ace editor, using [ace-builds](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/) (version 1.2.2) into an ember-cli (version 1.13.8) project.

1) Add the ace-builds distribution to the **bower_components** directory using command `bower install ace-builds --save` This should update your **bower.json** file with the new dependency.

2) As discussed in the Ember CLI documentation on [managing dependencies](http://www.ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies/) make sure you have **broccoli-funnel** installed using command `npm install broccoli-funnel --save-dev`

3) Insert `var Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');` into your **ember-cli-build.js** shown below.

4) Insert the `var extraAssets =` lines and pass `extraAssets` to the call to `app.toTree` as shown below.

5) Add `<script src="assets/ace/ace.js"></script>` to your app's **index.html** file just below the `{{content-for 'body'}}` line.

When you run your app this build will cause the global `window.ace` to be created. I suggest you use the debugger to make sure it is there.

Here is what my **ember-cli-build.js** file looks like (in earlier versions of ember-cli this was called **Brocfile.js**)

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var Funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });

  var extraAssets = new Funnel('bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict', {
    srcDir: '/',
    include: ['**/*.js'],
    destDir: '/assets/ace'
  });

  return app.toTree(extraAssets);
};
```

Note that ace-builds comes with various versions. Here I have chosen the **src-min-noconflict** build, but you could instead choose one of the others.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Ace doesn't use the same module system as Ember CLI (as far as I can tell), so you won't be able to import from it using the ES6 module syntax*. Your best bet is to just use the global `ace` object to do what you need to do.

* You *might* be able to import using ES6 module syntax. Ember CLI uses a version of AMD when transpiled, and it *might* be compatible with Ace's version. Try doing a `import Ace from 'ace/ace'` and see if that yields any results. If not, you'll have to use the global object.

Comment: Thanks @GJK, it doesn't seem to work. What's strange is if I throw a debugger statement right after the import statements, I see the right objects, but inside the actual component lifecycle hooks, they are undefined.

Comment: That... seems a little fishy. Would you mind posting the file where you're trying to use Ace? Maybe something will jump out at me if I see it.

Comment: There must be something off with the project setup, while setting up a test project to demonstrate the issue, it works with simple imports:

import ace from 'ace/ace';
import oop from 'ace/lib/oop';

Will dig in more and figure out what's going on and post a sample project soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can make Ace Editor component for Ember.js. 
Detailed explaination is also present [here](http://hbrysiewicz.github.io/2014-04-22-ace-ember-editor.html).

Here is an example implementation:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  data: {
    firstName: 'Heather',
    lastName: 'Brysiewicz',
    contact: {
      email: 'h.a.brysiewicz@gmail.com',
      phone: '815-246-2646',
      address: null
    }
  },

  rawData: function(key, val) {
    if (arguments.length == 2) {
      var data = null;
      try {
        data = JSON.parse(val);
      } catch (e) {}
      if (data) this.set('data', data);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(this.get('data'), null, 4);
  }.property('data')
});

App.AceEditorComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  content: function(key, val) {
    if (!this.editor) {
      this.preset = val;
      return val;
    }
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
      return this.editor.getSession().getValue();
    }
    var cursor = this.editor.getCursorPosition();
    this.editor.getSession().setValue(val);
    this.editor.moveCursorToPosition(cursor);
    return val;
  }.property(),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.editor = window.ace.edit('editor');
    this.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
    this.editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');

    var self = this;
    this.editor.on('change', function() {
      self.notifyPropertyChange('content');
    });

    if (this.preset) {
      this.set('content', this.preset);
      this.preset = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* Put your CSS here */

html,
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
pre {
  height: 120px;
}
#editor {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.5.0/ember.js"></script>
  <script src='http://hbrysiewicz.github.io/assets/js/ace/ace.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{ace-editor content=rawData}}
    <div id='preview'>
      {{rawData}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/ace-editor">
    <pre id='editor'></pre>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```